# Eliminar elemento de un array, cuando pulso en su botón eliminar jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas estoy intentando eliminar un elemento de un array que construyo a través de jquery, del siguiente modo.

```
var carrito = [];
    var namePrueba = '';
    //$(this).parents("tr").find("td").eq(0).text();
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.tablaListado').on( 'click', '.addPrueba', function (){
            var namePrueba = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").find("span").eq(0).text();
            carrito.push(namePrueba);
            //console.log(carrito); 
            if (carrito == ''){
                $("#noHay").css({"display": "block"});
                $("#solicita").css({"display": "none"});
            }else{
                $("#noHay").css({"display": "none"});
                $("#solicita").css({"display": "block"});
                $(".dentroPesu").animate({ scrollTop: $('.dentroPesu').prop("scrollHeight")}, 1000);
                $("#pruebasElegidas").append('<div class="producto"><div class="tamaProducto"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> '+namePrueba+'</div><div class="deleteFila"><a class="'+carrito+'"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> Eliminar</a></div>' );
            }
            console.log(carrito);
        });
});
```

De este modo obtengo esto, cuando voy añadiendo productos al array. En este caso, agregue 4 productos al arreglo.

```
(4) ["Alcalina Fosfatasa ", "Amfetaminas", "Albúmina en orina", "Alcalina Fosfatasa "]
0: "Alcalina Fosfatasa "
1: "Amfetaminas"
2: "Albúmina en orina"
3: "Alcalina Fosfatasa "
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Pero ahora intento eliminar un elemento del array, pero solo consigo eliminar el `div` pero no el elemento en el arreglo, además si ya tengo un elemento he intento añadirlo de nuevo, me lo permite.

```
$("body").on("click",".deleteFila", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        $(this).parent(carrito).remove(); //remove text box);
    return false;
```

Alguna sugerencia de como detectar el index, para poder eliminar el registro y comprobar si existe?

**Estoy probando así**

```
$(".deleteFila").click(function() {
  var indice = $(".deleteFila").index(this);
  //console.log(indice);
  carrito.splice(indice, 1);
  $(this).parent(".producto").remove();
  console.log(carrito);
})
```

Parece que la primera vez que elimino va bien, pero luego si elimino otro, me lo multiplica el console.log(carrito), y parece que lo borra completo.

Answer (score 0):

El primer fallo que tengo es que compruebo si la matriz `carrito` esta vacia cuando hago click en `.addPrueba` entonces es imposible que se encuentre vacia.

Entonces lo que he hecho es, primero crear bien la función que elimina el indice del arreglo.

```
$("body").on("click",".deleteFila", function(){
  var indice = $(".deleteFila").index(this);
  //console.log(indice);
  carrito.splice(indice, 1);
  $(this).parent(".producto").remove();
  estado();
})
```

Siempre que elimino un indice compruebo la función `estado` que la he creado nueva, si cuando comprueba su `.length` es `=0` realizo unas operaciones.

```
function estado(){
  if (carrito.length === 0){
    console.log("Está vacío!");
    $("#noHay").css({"display": "block"});
    $("#solicita").css({"display": "none"});
  }
}
```

No se si hay una forma más limpia de poder realizar la misma operación, estoy atento por si me recomendaís algo, saludos.

---

***Solo me falta, que a la hora de insertar un nuevo indice, compruebe si ya existe.***

Comment: Esto no debería ser una respuesta, sino **edición de la pregunta** y creo que falta información para ver de dónde tomas el nombre de los productos que agregas al carrito. Un ejemplo del HTML será suficiente.